# the macro '__TIME__' and '__TIMESTAMP__' can't refresh when developed with c++

Tags: c++, time

I developed the mac app with Qt, I want to write current time to the log.txt, so I use the macro `__TIME__`, and I print `__TIME__` value before write to the log.txt,

```
cout << "timeis----" << __TIME__ << endl;
```

It always shows me the older value which not I except, what should I do if I when get the current time every​ time, thanks a lot!

Comment: They are macros which means they get a specific value at compile time. They won’t change when run. You’ll have to use other methods to get the current time.

Comment: [This reference of standard C++ date and time facilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) might be useful.

Comment: thanks for your help,it's seem @Sami Kuhmonen is right

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible way to achieve what you are looking for, however one of the functions has been marked as deprecated and I have not currently found a work around, maybe in the near future when I have c++20 available this deprecation can be resolved with all of the new functionality that is being added to the `chrono` library. As for now this is just to demonstrate how you could get the time and date...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
#include <ctime>

int main() {
    auto currentTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::time_t time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t( currentTime );

    std::cout << "timeis---- " << std::ctime(&time) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Possible Output:

```
timeis---- Fri Feb 1 03:22:21 2019
```

However keep in mind that the function `std::ctime()` has been marked as deprecated.